# Diagonalizability of singular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Can a matrix that has dependent columns have different eigen values and be diagonalizable?

Comment: Yes, a square matrix has dependent columns if and only if zero is an eigenvalue. So it can still possibly be diagonalizable.

Comment: Consider the extreme case of a matrix of the form $\mathbf v\mathbf v^\top$, which has rank 1. It thus has multiple zero eigenvalues, but is certainly diagonalizable (due to symmetry).

Answer (score 6):

$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1=0,\,\lambda_2=1$, which are distinct (2 eigenvalues for a $2\times 2$ matrix means it's diagonalizable), and one of the columns is $\vec 0$, so the columns are linearly dependent. Having linearly dependent columns is equivalent to having zero as an eigenvalue. A matrix can have zero as an eigenvalue, and still be diagonalizable, as long as the geometric multiplicities equal the algebraic multiplicities for each eigenvalue.

Comment: Why is "having linearly dependent columns is equivalent to having zero as an eigenvalue"?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia from the invertible matrix theorem we know that $A$ has linearly independent columns if and only if zero is not an eigenvalue of $A$ ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix ). So if zero is an eigenvalue, then the columns must be linearly dependent. Similarly, if the columns are linearly dependent, then zero must be an eigenvalue.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia If the columns $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ of matrix $A$ are linearly dependent,  there are scalars $c_1, \ldots, c_n$, not all $0$, such that $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i A_i = 0$.  But $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i A_i = A  c$, where $c$ is the column vector with entries $c_1, \ldots, c_n$.  And then $c$ is a nonzero vector in the null space of $A$, i.e. it is an eigenvector of $A$ for eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: @Dave if possible can you please explain your last statement in more detail: "the geometric multiplicities equal the algebraic multiplicities for each eigenvalue."

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia this statement is equivalent to saying there are $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors for an $n\times n$ matrix. If the algebraic multiplicities equal the geometric multiplicities for each eigenvalue, then the geometric multiplicities are all maximized, so there will be $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: Can you please explain this statement- " If the algebraic multiplicities equal the geometric multiplicities for each eigenvalue, then the geometric multiplicities are all maximized."

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia geometric multiplicities are less than or equal to algebraic multiplicities (which are both nonnegative integers). So to maximize geometric multiplicities, they must be equal to the algebraic multiplicities. These are really just ways of saying the matrix is diagonalizable. This link may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix

Answer (score 1):

To generelize Dave's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2055022/22998):

An $n \times n$ matrix is diagonalizable if-and-only-if [it has $n$ independent eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix) (which is not the same as $n$ independent columns in the matrix). Some of these eigenvectors can very well have eigenvalue 0 - which you definitely get if your matrix has linearly dependent columns.